# Authorization through certificate

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl

The server contains the certificate (*.crt). And there are two different users. One is set in the browser certificate (*.p12), which signed the server certificate. The user enters the folder **example.com/a**

A user who doesn't have a certificate enters **example.com/b**

How to do it using the settings apache? Redirect?

Comment: Off topic, belongs on serverfault.com, and not very clear either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SSLVerifyClient optional
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars

SSLCACertificateFile path/to/file

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} SUCCESS
RewriteRule   ^/(.*) /a/(.*) [L]

RewriteCond   %{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY} FAILED
RewriteRule   ^/(.*) /b/(.*) [L]
```